# VBA - Loop through multiple subfolders on a network location with date search criteria/ Improve search speed

Tags: vba, loops, date, subdirectory

Purpose of my question and of the VBA code:
Get specific data (a couple columns) from each one of the "table.csv" file in a network directory. Each networkdirectory/subfolders01/subfolders02 contains one "table.csv" file but 100 other subfolders are included in each network/subfolders01. The other folders are not needed, the only one we are interested in is subfolder02 for each subfolder01. The number of subfolders01 in the network directory is about 15000. However I only need subfolders01 from Jan2020 to Apr2020,for example (200 subfolders). 
Final purpose is to trend data.

Issue: 
I am trying to understand how I could improve the VBA code that I am currently using.
This code goes through each subfolder one by one and then check the date and file name.
I am wondering if there is a way to add any search filters criteria for subfolder date and name to have a faster loop.
How can we avoid the code to go through each subfolders?

Please see below the code I am using,
I really appreciate your time and hope my request is clear.

'''

```
Function GetFiles(startPath As String) As Collection 
Dim fso As Object, rv As New Collection, colFolders As New Collection, fpath As String
Dim subFolder As Object, f, dMinfold, dtMod
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dMinfold = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Enter_Date").Cells(2, 1)

colFolders.Add startPath

Do While colFolders.Count > 0
    fpath = colFolders(1)
    colFolders.Remove 1
    'process subfolders
    For Each subFolder In fso.getfolder(fpath).subfolders
        If subFolder.DateLastModified >= dMinfold Then
            colFolders.Add subFolder.Path
        End If
    Next subFolder
    'process files
    f = Dir(fso.buildpath(fpath, "*Table.csv"), vbNormal)
    Do While f <> ""
        f = fso.buildpath(fpath, f)
        dtMod = FileDateTime(f)
        If dtMod >= dMinfold And Right(f, 3) = "csv" Then
            rv.Add f
        End If

        f = Dir()
    Loop
Loop
Set GetFiles = rv
End Function'''
```

Then I have my code to get transfer data from each file.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered Get & Transform (power query)? Filtering/Merging CSV from a folder is built-in functionality with no need for VBA.

Comment: Thank you, no I haven't... I am not familiar with the option. Does that option allow to go in different subfolders? May I ask you if you have any guidance regarding the procedure?

Comment: Here's a demo of somebody combining csv from one folder, it should be possible to filter on subfolder01 and subfolder02 name but I can't test at my current location unfortunately. It's just one option to consider, vba is perfectly valid also.  https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/power-query-get-files-from-a-folder

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be a way better option for what I am trying to accomplish!

Comment: Loading all the data is still very slow, I am having the same question with Power query. Is it possible fo filter by Date and file type BEFORE getting all the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put in screenshots to clear up the Get & Transform method, since it is the GUI approach rather than code.

It is possible to filter before loading contents, which will speed things up significantly.
I tried with a few thousand subfolders filtered down to 20, loads instantly.

Here's the initial screen for get data from folder
[image: Initial results for get data from folder]

You can then filter on path. In your case it will be based on the date from the folder name.
[image]

Now that it's filtered you can expand the content using the header button.
[image]

Inside content, you'll have to expand again to convert from csv to excel table
[image]

Choose/rename columns as needed, then hit "close and load" to drop it into excel.
Default is to a new table, but you can "load to" if something more custom is needed.
[image]

Here's your output. You can right-click refresh or refresh from vba as needed.
[image]

Edit- Just noticed that I used .txt rather than .csv for the files. Might change how a step or two looks in the middle, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much. However my issue here is when I filter the columns, it gets very slow. I believe it is because there is so many rows, I was wondering if there was a way to have a search criteria before displaying the results in the query and having to filter. does it make sense ?

Comment: Sorry just edited my comment, if you can help me a little more that would be great!

Comment: You're filtering before loading the data, right? The filtering step should be when you just see a list of file names.

Comment: Yes, and this step gets very slow... for the date filter it is not bad but when I filter the name of the file it is extremely slow... I have a lot of different files and I just want the "Table.csv" files.

Comment: I'm a bit stuck, sorry. If it's just a few thousand rows at that point I would not expect excel to have trouble with filtering.

Comment: I understand. no problem thank you for helping. Let's see, do you know if there is a way to add a search criteria in the advanced editor such as Query=date.from(...)?

Comment: docs for search criteria: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectrows

Comment: Thank you.. this is a way to filter after the table is displayed. so basically just to clarify If I refresh the query I cannot add a pre-filter for the date, the query will always have to go through all the folders and files and then filter?

Comment: A "table" just means the previous processing step. That would include the list of filenames displayed before expanding contents.